# You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available error

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have been using vue in a proyect recently and when im trying to compile my brwoser page is white and the error **You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.** is on the browser console

I have this structure in my **index.html** file

```
<body id="page">
    <div id="app">
      
      <h1>{{Title}}</h1>

      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="input" v-model="username"/>
      
      <div>
        <button id="button" v-on:click="play">Play</button>
      </div>

      <h1>{{Records}}</h1>

      <dl id="list">
        <dt v-for="user of users" id="data">
          {{user.Username}} - {{user.Score}}
        </dt>
      </dl>
    </div>

    <script src="Views/welcomePage.js"></script>
  </body>
```

And here is where i am importing vue, my welcomePage.js file, and i need to import exactly 'vue' because i need to export the data that will be on the username variable once you write the data on the input in the html file so i cant change the import to 'vue/dist/vue.js'

```
window.axios = require('axios');
import Vue from 'vue';

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        Records: 'Records',
        Title: 'Snake',
        users:[],
        username: '',
    },

    mounted: function(){
        axios.get('http://localhost:3000')
            .then(res => this.users = res.data);
    },

    methods:{
        play(){
            console.log(app)
            window.location.href = 'snake.html'
        } 
    }
})

export default app.$data.username
```

How can I see my page well?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully a pretty easy one - you are using a flavor of `vue.runtime.js` instead of the regular `vue.js`.

You can see an [explanation of the different builds in the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Explanation-of-Different-Builds).

The runtime-only build is a bit smaller, but is really meant for different use cases, like when running from Vue CLI and `npm run` (a very popular way to use Vue) or if you're calling html-rendering functions natively from JavaScript (not popular).

You need the "full" build, or "full (production)" build, each of which have the template compiler built in. It's probably linked from your HTML page, so just change your reference the the appropriate vue.js file.